# Is it possible to create a generic type that is a descendant of a type in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, generics, inheritance

For example:

```
class BaseType {
    void showMessage() { 
        print("This is Base Type");
    }
}

class DescendantType extends BaseType {
    @override
    void showMessage() {
        print("This is DescendantType");
    }
    void descendantFunction() {
        print("Hello World!");
    }
}

class OtherType {
    void showMessage() {
        print("This is OtherType");
    }
}

class Implementer<T extends BaseType> {
    T data;

    Implementer(T input) {
        this.data = input;
        this.data.showMessage();
    }
}

void main() {
    var base = Implementer(BaseType()); // print "This is BaseType"
    var descendant = Implementer(DescendantType()); // print "This is "DescendantType"
    descendant.descendantFunction(); // this won't be possible if T is changed instead into BaseType (polymorphism)
    var other = Implementer(OtherType()); // must be error; OtherType is not descendant of BaseType
}
```

Is a thing like this possible in Flutter?

The difference between this and the actual polymorphism implementation is that the end result of type of "data" field is the actual class (BaseType or DescendantType) instead of ambiguous BaseType or its descendants where I still have to check again whether "data" field is BaseType or DescendantType.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Your code is correct, except the last line where ```other``` will raise an error. You won't need to check if ```data``` is of type ```BaseType``` the class declaration will ensure that.

If you need to know whether the data is ```DescendantType``` then your class declaration is not the right one, and yes you'll have to check it with an ```if```.

Comment: You cannot do third implementation because `OtherType` is not a subtype of `BaseType`. Flutter will show warning. First two implementations are valid.

Comment: I think it is better to create `BaseInterface` which will be used as generic type but thereby all classes should implement those interface.